# using summarize in ddply to get entire row based on max() of one column

Tags: r, plyr

df1

```
  primer timepoints        mean          sde
    Acan          0   1.0000000 0.000000e+00
    Acan         20   0.8758265 7.856192e-02
    Acan         40   1.0575400 4.680159e-02
    Acan         60   1.2399106 2.238616e-01
    Acan        120   1.1710685 2.085558e-02
    Acan        240   1.6430670           NA
    Acan        360   1.7747940           NA
```

all I want is the max value of mean (for any of these timepoints) w/ it's corresponding sde.

```
   ## this will only get me the mean obviously 
   x <- ddply(x, .(primer), summarize, max = max(mean)) 

 primer        max
   Acan   1.774794


## if I were to do this I would obviously not have just the maximum values 
   x <- ddply(x. .(primer,sde), summarize, max = max(mean))
```

one idea I had would be to may be to include timepoints in the df then match the two data frames to get a column of sdes. Then cbind that to the df w/ only means.

But I feel as if there is an easier way to do this w/ ddply

Comment: If you don't have to use `summarise`:  `ddply(x, .(primer), function(DF) DF[DF$mean == max(DF$mean),])`

Comment: Using your example data, it's easy to pull out the row that contains the maximum mean using: df1[df1$mean == max(df1$mean),]. But perhaps you have other primer names and need to group by those?

Comment: yes I do, but this works fine. I only need single values of primer, so I think that's fine

Comment: @Justin Can you or the OP post this as an answer, so this question doesn't remain in limbo as unanswered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have to use summarise:

```
ddply(x, .(primer), function(DF) DF[DF$mean == max(DF$mean),])
```