# Matching function within standard plyr notation

Tags: r, plyr

This should be straightforward, but trying to insert any sort of match[] syntax into the ddply argument returns errors.. I'm looking for a way to do it within standard plyr functions, if possible.

All I want to do is summarise a data frame, then for one of the items where we're finding a given value, match it to its corresponding value for another item in the data frame.

It was done here: [Summarise in ddply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063527/using-summarize-in-ddply-to-get-entire-row-based-on-max-of-one-column), but that syntax gets messy.

Here's an example:

```
data <-  data.frame(
    spend = sample(50:100,50,replace=T),
    trials = sample(100:200,50,replace=T),
    country = sample(c("usa","canada","uk"),50,replace = T)
    )
```

I want to summarise and get the max value for "Spend" by country. Whatever that value is, I want to then pull in its corresponding value for "Trials".

```
data2 <- ddply(data, .(country), summarise,
    spend = max(spend),
....
```

Can I do this within "summarise" or do I have to use a custom function(df) parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding one letter to the package,

```
library(dplyr)
chain(data, 
      group_by(country),
      filter(spend == max(spend)))
```

Comment: This is awesome. I'm new to dplyr... how does the filter argument pull in both spend and its corresponding trials number?

Comment: i can only guess -- first time I've used dplyr

Comment: @MarcTulla that is a shortcut for `filter(group_by(data, country), spend == max(spend))`. `filter()` keeps all existing columns.

Comment: @hadley thanks for the followup! I guess I'm still confused: Using filter() to keep the existing columns -- does that function by default pull in whatever was the matching value to max(spend)?

Comment: @MarcTulla `speed == max(spend)` evaluates to a logical vector for each group. `filter()` keeps all rows corresponding to TRUEs

Answer (score 2):

You can use `which.max`:

```
ddply(data, 
      .(country), 
      summarise, 
      trials=trials[which.max(spend)],
      spend=max(spend))
```

Or more explicitly if you're doing something complex:

```
ddply(data, 
      .(country),
      summarise,
      trials=head(trials[spend == max(spend)], 1),
      spend=max(spend))
```

The `head(...)` call is in case there are two rows with `max(spend)`.  Also, the order of the arguments that follow `summarise` is important...

---

Well, that result is not what I expected!  In any case, I'd use `dplyr` (baptiste's answer) or `data.table`:

```
d <- data.table(data)

d[, .SD[spend==max(spend)], by=country]
```

Comment: Hmmm Justin, I ran this and it didn't match up. I'm just seeing Trials = the first "trials" number, not the one that matches the max value for Spend within a country

Comment: there's a **very nasty bug**! It appears that the results depend on the order of the expressions after `summarise`. Try inverting the two lines, it works!

Comment: @baptiste wow... correct again.  and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's reusing the same variable name in multiple places.